# how can I do an addition of all price elements from a json array in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have the following JSON array:

```
fruits = [{"fruit":"banana","amount":"2","price":"1"},{"fruit":"apple","amount":"5","price":"2"},{"fruit":"kiwi","amount":"1","price":"5"}]
```

How can I calculate all the "price" values together? The result should be 8.

I have so far the following but problems accessing the price items:

```
function count(fruits) {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
        sum = sum + fruits[i][price];
    }
    return sum;
}

console.log(count(fruits)
```

Thank you!

Comment: That is an array of object literals. There is no such thing as a [JSON array](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). (That article is specifically about objects but the same applies to arrays).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access them like:

```
fruits[i].price
```

and then convert them to numbers before adding them:

```
parseInt(fruits[i].price, 10);
```

Final code:

```
fruits = [{"fruit":"banana","amount":"2","price":"1"},{"fruit":"apple","amount":"5","price":"2"},{"fruit":"kiwi","amount":"1","price":"5"}]
var total = 0;
for(var i=0; i<fruits.length; i++){
    total += parseInt(fruits[i].price, 10);
}

alert(total); //8
```

**[See the DEMO here](http://jsfiddle.net/j9zfu4wn/4/)**

Comment: [Always use a radix](http://www.michaelgaigg.com/blog/2008/10/07/the-importance-of-the-javascript-parseint-radix/) when using `parseInt`!

Comment: Wow less than 30 seconds after my comment :) You didn't get the instance in the final code and fiddle. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. The line

   ```
   sum = sum + fruits[i][price];
   ```

   should be

   ```
   sum = sum + fruits[i].price;
   ```

   or even

   ```
   sum += fruits[i].price;
   ```

   Your code was trying to use a *variable* called `price`, not the `price` property of the fruit entry.
2. Your prices are strings, so we want to make sure they're converted to numbers when summing them up. You have lots of options there: Apply a unary `+` to them, pass them into `Number()`, or use `parseInt(..., 10)`. Below I'll go with a unary `+`, but there are pluses (no pun!) and minuses to each.

```js
var fruits = [{"fruit":"banana","amount":"2","price":"1"},{"fruit":"apple","amount":"5","price":"2"},{"fruit":"kiwi","amount":"1","price":"5"}]

function count(fruits) {
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
    sum += +fruits[i].price; // <=== change is here
  }
  return sum;
}

display(count(fruits));

function display(msg) {
  var p = document.createElement('p');
  p.innerHTML = String(msg);
  document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```

With ES5's array additions (which can be shimmed on older browsers), you can do this with either `forEach` or `reduce`:

`forEach`:

```js
var fruits = [{"fruit":"banana","amount":"2","price":"1"},{"fruit":"apple","amount":"5","price":"2"},{"fruit":"kiwi","amount":"1","price":"5"}]

function count(fruits) {
  var sum = 0;
  fruits.forEach(function(fruit) {
    sum += +fruit.price;
  });
  return sum;
}

display(count(fruits));

function display(msg) {
  var p = document.createElement('p');
  p.innerHTML = String(msg);
  document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```

`reduce`:

```js
var fruits = [{"fruit":"banana","amount":"2","price":"1"},{"fruit":"apple","amount":"5","price":"2"},{"fruit":"kiwi","amount":"1","price":"5"}]

function count(fruits) {
  var sum = 0;
  sum = fruits.reduce(function(prev, fruit) {
    return prev + +fruit.price;
  }, 0);
  return sum;
}

display(count(fruits));

function display(msg) {
  var p = document.createElement('p');
  p.innerHTML = String(msg);
  document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has 2 errors:

To access the price property

```
fruits[i][price]
```

should be

```
fruits[i]['price'] or fruits[i].price
```

The price property is of type string. So the '+' operator will concatenate the price strings. To add them together you need to change their type to number by doing

```
parseInt(fruits[i]['price'], 10) or +fruits[i]['price']
```

If the price property doesn't contain a valid number the result will be NaN (not a number). You could avoid that by using the or operator.

```
+fruits[i]['price'] || 0
```

Using the ES5 Array extensions supported by all modern browsers you could write

```
fruits.reduce(function(m,v) { return m + (+v.price);}, 0);
```

With ES6 in future browsers this could be reduced to

```
 fruits.reduce((m,v) => m + (+v.price), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors in your code. 
The first one is here: `sum = sum + fruits[i][price];`
 you are trying to use a variable called price, not the property price of the object. You can access to the property using `fruits[i]["price"]` or `fruits[i].price`.
To obtain a number, when you are doing the sum, you need to convert the strings in numbers, to do that you can use `parseInt(fruits[i]["price"]);`. Last error in the last line you forgot the parenthesis and semicolon.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/29w548Lj/)

Answer (score 0):

your function is OK, just add parseInt for it to convert to type int, and has a incorrect syntax in fruits[i][price].
You've two option:

```
 fruits[i]["price"] 
 OR
 fruits[i].price
```

In my opinion, I would add a small logic code to check if it's a number or not. and return 0 if input data is undefined or null.

```
var fruits = [{"fruit":"banana","amount":"2","price":"1"},{"fruit":"apple","amount":"5","price":"2"},{"fruit":"kiwi","amount":"1","price":"5"}]

function count(data) {
    var sum = 0;
    if(data === void 0 ) return 0; // no array input
    data.forEach(function(fruit) {
       console.log(fruit);
       sum += parseInt(fruit.price || 0 ); // if price is undefined, null or NaN, return 0
    })
    return sum;
}

display(count(fruits));

function display(msg) {
  var p = document.createElement('p');
  p.innerHTML = String(msg);
  document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this simple code snippet.

You don't need jQuery to do this operation. Simple JS would do.

```
var sum = 0;
for(var item in fruits){
    sum += ~~(fruits[item].price)
}
console.log(sum)
```

Cheers!